# How can I disable external inheritance (without classes) in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor, internal

How can I disable external inheritance without using classes? I know it can be done with classes like this:

```
public abstract class NoInherit
{
    internal NoInherit() { }
}

public sealed class MyType : NoInherit { /* ... */ }
```

But not with interfaces. I don't want to use classes because I want to inherit `MyType` from another class and C# doesn't support multiple inheritance.

Perhaps I should explain better what I'm trying to do. I'm attempting to create an object-like class but that only accepts some types.

```
List<NoInherit> x = new List<NoInherit>();
x.Add(new MyType()); // OK
x.Add(new MyType2()); // OK
x.Add(123); // ERROR
```

Comment: Oh, I see what you are getting at now.  But you can't do that.  The only reason you can get away with it in the class-based version is because you're kind of "cheating" by making the constructor internal.  Since interfaces don't have constructors, that idea is a non-starter.

Comment: Why not roll your own IList<T> class and handle the constraints in the Add method?